# Excel using auto-generated hyperlinks to hide rows in a table

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a table where I want to be able to hide individual rows at a mouse click. The (seemingly) easiest solution I've found is to have a column filled with hyperlinks that call a macro to hide the row that they're in.

There are two ways of calling macros from hyperlinks: using `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` with manual hyperlinks, and using `=HYPERLINK`.

The former works fine, except there's no way (that I've found) to have them generate automatically when new rows are added to the table. I would have to either manually copy them down every time, which is unviable, or add them with VBA, which adds a bunch of complexity to an otherwise simple task.

The latter generates fine, being a formula, but it doesn't actually work. It doesn't trigger `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`, and when using `=HYPERLINK("#MyFunction()")` it just doesn't hide rows (or do much other than editing cells contents).

```
Function MyFunction()
    Set MyFunction = Selection
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Function
```

Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: have you tried grouping columns/rows and etc?
SHIFT+ALT+LEFT/RIGHT arrow

Comment: ...I didn't know that was a thing. Can it be automatically applied to each row of a table as you add more data?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a Hyperlink, you could handle a Double Click event on the table column

Something like

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NameOfTableColumn As String
    
    On Error GoTo EH:
    NameOfTableColumn = "DblClickToHide" ' update to suit your table
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Target.ListObject.ListColumns(NameOfTableColumn).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Cancel = True
    End If
Exit Sub
EH:
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where the table to be clicked exists. Clicking on each cell in its first column (dynamic to rows adding/insertions/deletions), the clicked row will be hidden:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim tbl As ListObject
   If Target.cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
   Set tbl = Me.ListObjects(1) 'you may use here the table name
   If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

It would be good to think about a way to unhide the hidden row if/when necessary. If only a row should be hidden at a time, it is easy to unhide all the rest of column cells...